# Packing int16 into fixed2 (Red + Green)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl, shaderlab

In Unity, a heightmap is internally shorted as an Int16 (note that only 0-32767 is used). I want send the heightmap to the GPU, and ideally only use 16-bits.

It seems like the best way to do that would be to encode the heightmap value to a RG16 render texture (since in Unity I can't choose a single channel 16-bit integer format), and pack/unpack as necessary.

Here is the heightmap texture I'm sending to the GPU (via a CPU-side C# script):

```
const int Size = 1024;
Color32[] colours = new Color32[Size * Size];
for (int y = 0; y < Size; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < Size; x++) {
        float height = heights[y, x]; // With Unity it's correct to flip the x/y axes
        short s = (short)(heights[y, x] * short.MaxValue);

        byte upper = (byte)(s >> 7); // Shift 7 and not 8 since we don't want values outside of 0-32767 anyway.
        byte lower = (byte)(s & 255);

        colours[y * size + x] = new Color32(upper, lower, 0, 0);
    }
}
tex.SetPixels32(colours);
tex.Apply();
```

I am running into a confusing issue where there seems to be a large loss of precision when unpacking the heightmap sample. I've tried the bitwise way:

```
float HeightmapSample(float u, float v) {
    fixed2 height  = tex2Dlod(_Heightmap, float4(u, v, 0.f, 0.f)).rg;
    int2 heightInt = height * 255.f;
    int unpacked   = (heightInt.r << 7) | heightInt.g;
    return unpacked / 32767.f; // Renormalize
}
```

And a (possibly) funky floating point method:

```
float HeightmapSample(float u, float v) {
    fixed2 height = tex2Dlod(_Heightmap, float4(u, v, 0.f, 0.f)).rg;
    return height.r + (height.g / 128.f) - (1.f / 128.f);
}
```

Both methods don't produce even close to the same as the ground truth:
[image: What I'm getting]

Comment: by the way, you can set textures with other formats than RGBA 32bits using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.R16.html

Comment: @BriceV.Thanks but I'm already aware of that. Also note that RenderTextures don't have as many format options in Unity compared to Texture2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 2 days of hunting down to culprit I realized I had a shader that was incorrectly re-encoding the heightmap every time my plugin loaded. I delibrately didn't fix that shader because I was focusing on the problem above instead, but it turned it to be the problem!